# Laravel Eloquent One to Many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have a Restaurants table and an Offers table. One restaurant may have multiple Offers. I am trying to create the relation between Restaurant - Offers using hasMany() method.

Table structure :

**1) restaurant**

- id
- restaurant name

**2) offers**

- offer_id
- restaurant_ID
- offer_price

Code : In the Restaurant Model in am doing something like this

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Restaurant extends Model
{


    public function offer(){

         return $this->hasMany('Offer');
    }
}
```

and in view, i tried printing the result using

below code in view

```
 foreach ($restaurants_data as $key => $value) {

         print_r($value->offer);
    ?>
```

**Routes** code :

```
Route::get('/home/restaurants',function(){
  $restaurants = DB::table('restaurants')->simplepaginate(3);
  return view('restaurants',['restaurants_data'=>$restaurants]);
});
```

[image]

But i am not getting the offers data, where am i going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: You're not doing anything with `$value->offer`...

Comment: @Devon I tried doing print_r . I have corrected it in question

Comment: I recommend you not use views to debug or test models.  Try writing test cases or using `artisan tinker`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the relationships defined in the Model, you have to use the Model:

```
$restaurants = \App\Restaurant::simplePaginate(3);
```

The query builder doesn't return model instances, it returns stdClass objects.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't worked, for me. 

I changed the routes as below :

Route::get('/home/restaurants',function(){
  // $restaurants = DB::table('restaurants')->simplepaginate(3);
  $restaurants = \App\Restaurant::simplePaginate(3);
  return view('restaurants',['restaurants_data'=>$restaurants]);
});

Comment: This is the reason the property $offers is undefined, if you have another issue, open a new question for that.

Comment: added another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46240903/issue-querying-laravel-eloquent-relationship

Comment: @adi Try using just `paginate`, maybe `simplePaginate` isn't allowing for relationships.  I don't normally use simplePaginate.

Answer (score 0):

In the model change the code like this :

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Restaurant extends Model
{
    public function offer(){    
         return $this->hasMany('Offer','restaurant_ID','id');
    }
}
```