# Issue querying laravel eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, orm

This is with reference to this question :

[Laravel Eloquent One to Many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46240576/laravel-eloquent-one-to-many-relationship?noredirect=1#comment79445047_46240576)

I tried the suggested way, but couldn't resolve. Please help. Below is the  changes i have done :

Earlier :

```
//Route for Restaurants Page
Route::get('/home/restaurants',function(){
  $restaurants = DB::table('restaurants')->simplepaginate(3);
  return view('restaurants',['restaurants_data'=>$restaurants]);
});
```

Changed as per suggestion :

```
Route::get('/home/restaurants',function(){
  // $restaurants = DB::table('restaurants')->simplepaginate(3);
  $restaurants = \App\Restaurant::simplePaginate(3);
  return view('restaurants',['restaurants_data'=>$restaurants]);
});
```

In Restaurant model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Restaurant extends Model
{


    public function offer(){

         return $this->hasMany('Offer');
    }
}
```

In view, now I am trying to access it by dumping the values.

```
 <?php
    var_dump($restaurants_data->offer);

    ?>
```

Error : [image]

**After doing dd()**

[image]

Comment: Why did the the suggested way work? What was the error? Please be more specific.

Comment: what are you trying to do? are you trying to reference the offers associated with the restaurants?

Comment: Yes, i want to list all the offers of a particular restaurant.

Comment: @adi What is the error you get with the current code? It looks correct.

Comment: Also, please try `$this->hasMany('App\Offer');`

Comment: I tried this, no luck.. I have uploaded the error snap too

Comment: what does it say if you dd(\App\Restaurant::with('offer')); in the controller?

Comment: I have uploaded the snap with dd.. it is dumping the query array.

Comment: You have no instance of the Restaurant of the model. This only works if you have a Restaurant and you then want to have the related fields.

Comment: Can a relationship have more than one offer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would suggest changing your Offer Relationship to:

```
public function offers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Offer::class, 'restaurant_ID', 'id');
}
```

The above assumes that the `Offer` class and `Restaurant` class are in the same namespace. If they're not please add the correct namespace or import the `Offer` model in to the class.

Secondly, because you're paginating the results you will end up with a collection of `Restaurant` models (even if there is only one), so you will need to loop through them to get access to the offers for each model. I would also suggest [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the results e.g.

`Route`:

```
Route::get('/home/restaurants', function () {

    $restaurants = \App\Restaurant::with('offers')->simplePaginate(3);

    return view('restaurants', compact('restaurants'));
});
```

in your view:

```
@foreach($restaurants as $restaurant)

    @foreach($restaurant->offers as $offer)

        {!! dump($offer) !!}

    @endforeach

@endforeach

{{ $restaurants->links() }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you replace
`$restaurants = \App\Restaurant::paginate(3);` and amend the blade code to say

```
<?php
  foreach($restraunts_data as $resturant) {
     if(count($restaurant->offer) {
        print_r($restaurant->offer);
     }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the models incorrectly. You run no queries and you attempt to run a static method on the `Restaurant` class without selecting any restaurants. As far as I know is this not supported by Eloquent. If you look at the error message it complains that there are no property `$offer`.

Try to run some query, and the select the related `Offer`. This should work as expected.

For example:

```
$offers = \App\Restaurant::find(1)->offer;
```

This will return the many `Offer` relations for the `Restaurant` with ID 1.

Comment: The query is handled by the paginate method, just like if you were to run `Restaurant::get()` without any conditions..